# Drawing points around polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I'm drawing many blocks like these

[image]

Then I need to surround them by points at fixed distances from each other like so

[image]

But I have a lot of blocks, and many points to calculate the distance, and then draw. I normally use the measure tool around the block, and then add the points on top

This process in extremely tedious, so I had a thought of drawing a line and by a certain way break that line into points that are separated from each other by certain distances and transferring those points into a different layer.

Is there anyway this way can work or does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: You could buffer the blocks then convert the buffers to points?

Answer (score 10):

there's three steps to this

- **buffer** (as mentioned by DPSSpatial). This draws an outline a fixed distance away from your blocks. Find this in **Vector > Geoprocessing tools > Fixed distance buffer**
- make a line layer from the buffer layer (**Vector > Geometry Tools > Polygons to Lines**). This is needed for the next step
- **chainage** (specifically the **qchainage plugin**) on the line layer. This puts points around the line at fixed intervals.

Here's an example, I've buffered the buildings by 5 meters, and used Qchainage to place points 5m apart on the buffered layer...

[image]

Comment: +1 A simple, but very effective approach!

Comment: Good answer. As an alternative to qchainage plugin one could use the Processing GRASS v.to.points, if you wants the point interpolation to be reset at each vertex or use the three steps in a processing model.

Comment: thanks for the method, but the thing is i cant save the produced qchainage layer as an shp file , and it disappears each time i exit and reopen the file,.. do you know a way around it?